# How to extract meta tags from website?

Tags: php, meta

I'm currently using get_meta_tags to get the tags from a variety of websites like this:

```
<?php $tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.stackoverflow.com/'); ?>
```

This is the code I'm using to display that information:

```
<?php echo $tags['description']; ?><br /><br />
<?php echo $tags['keywords']; ?>
```

Now there are two things I can't figure out how to do:

1. How do I make it so that `<br /><br />` is removed if the meta description doesn't exist?  Basically do that there isn't extra lines at the top causing an empty spot.
2. How can I make the keywords all links to my domain such as 
   ``` http://mysite.com/keyword/coding``http://mysite.com/keyword/website-builder ``` or `http://mysite.com/keyword/php-help`?

Comment: for first one: echo $tags['description'] ? $tags['description']."<br /><br />" : '';

Comment: @Akam hint: use backticks to delimit code in comments

Comment: @Akam that isn't working on my end and `description` is in it twice by mistake I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.ebay.com/');

if(trim($tags['description'])!='') //if description is set and not empty
{
    echo ($tags['description']).'<br /><br />';
}

echo $tags['keywords'];

$keywordArray = explode(",", $tags['keywords']); //split string with keywords in an array
foreach($keywordArray as $keyword) //for each entry in the array
{
    echo "http://www.mysite.com/".urlencode(trim($keyword)); //echo your URL. Encode the keyword in case special chars are present
}

?>
```

Akam gave you the short notation of the if-statement, I personally prefer the long notation.

Comment: Any way to change it from the + sign to a - sign?

Comment: you can use str_replace to do that -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I just got done testing it out and it's displaying a list of the keywords and then a list of the URLs.  However, what I'm really looking for is something along the lines of `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/first-keyord">first keyword</a>, <a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/second-keyord">second keyword</a>, <a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/third-keyord">third keyword</a>,` and so on. Sorry if I didn't explain that correctly above.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but you should at least try to do it yourself. 1.) remove the line echo $tags['keywords'] -> so the keywords are not printed anymore. 2.) change the line with the url in it so it fits your needs, probably something like: `echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/"'.trim($keyword).'">'.trim($keyword).'</a>';`

Comment: I got the first part done before you mentioned it actually, it's the second part I've been stuck on.  This is what I have entered:  `echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/"'.trim($keyword).'">'.trim($keyword).'</a>, ';` but when it shows on the page it's a list of the keywords but they are all linked directly to `http://www.mysite.com/keywords/` so I'm not sure why that second `'.trim($keyword).'` isn't working...

Comment: it's because of the " after keywords/ -> remove it and you should be good -> and yes, I did it wrong in my example :)

Comment: That works perfect!  Thank you so much!  I did have one other quick question about this if you have time.  Right now they keywords are showing like `ebay, electronics, cars, clothing, apparel, collectibles, sporting goods, digital cameras, antiques, tickets, jewelry, online shopping, auction, online auction,` - is there a way to automatically remove that last unneeded comma?

Comment: you print the comma at the end of the line, so it's also printed for the last keyword. The easiest solution is to add a generic link at the end of the list. E.g. `echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/home">Home</a>';` at the end of your code after }