# Hyperlinking keywords from get_meta_tags

Tags: php

I'm using `get_meta_tags` to extract keywords from a webpage right now but I need each of those keywords linked to my website when displayed.

Here's my code:

```
<?php echo $tags['description']; ?><br /><br />
<?php echo $tags['keywords']; ?>
```

This is the text pulled from HostGator.com for the keywords:

```
 web hosting, hosting, webhosting
```

I need each of those keywords linked to my website like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/web-hosting">web hosting</a>, 
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/hosting">hosting</a>, 
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/webhosting">webhosting</a>
```

Nothing I've tried seems to be working with this so I was hoping you guys could help out.

Comment: please check my answer and my sample code in your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950548/how-to-extract-meta-tags-from-website/14951157

Comment: `echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/'.$tags['keywords'].'">'.$tags['keywords'].'</a>';`

Comment: @Thorsten just responded.

Comment: @YoavKadosh That just caused this:  http://www.mysite.com/keywords/web%20hosting,%20hosting,%20webhosting,%20reseller%20hosting,%20vps%20hosting,%20dedicated%20servers,%20dedicated%20hosting,%20website%20hosting,%20dedicated%20server,%20web%20host,%20reseller,%20cpanel

Comment: I see, do you have your keywords as an array or as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have your tags as text, rather than an array.

```
$data = 'web hosting, hosting, webhosting';
$tags = explode(', ' , $data);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/'.$tag.'>'.$tag.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have try this way.

```
<?php
foreach($data as $tags)
{
    ?><a href="http://www.mysite.com/keywords/web-hosting/"<?php echo $tags['keywords']; ?>><?php echo $tags['keywords']; ?></a><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what that did but it just caused the whole area to go blank.